# curl command not working in dockerfile - curl: (7) Failed to connect to ... port 443: Connection refused

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile

I have created a dockerfile, containing the following command:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
(...)
RUN curl -L https://github.com/(...)/releases/download/1.2.3.gz -o /tmp/1.2.3.gz
```

I receive the following error when I build my image with `docker build - < dockerfile`

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -L https://github.com/(...)/releases/download/1.2.3.gz -o /tmp/1.2.3.gz' returned a non-zero code: 7
```

If I run the same command (without "/bin/sh -c") **in the console of the server it works**

Adding "-v" to the curl requests gives some more information:

```
* Trying 66.94.108.97...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55c810c450f0)
* connect to 66.94.108.97 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

The IP Address it tells me here is a Contabo address (which is the provider of the cloud server). So maybe this is a DNS problem?  I have set Docker to use 8.8.8.8 DNS server in /etc/default/docker

A ping to github.com from my server console outputs a different IP: 140.82.121.4

Answer (score 1):

My workaround after many hours of search an error:

```
docker build --add-host github.com:140.82.121.4 - < dockerfile
```

You can add individual host resolving in the command using the --add-host tag:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options